# Find graphs on 5 vertices with 22 cycles, 13 cycles and 12 cycles

Tags: graph-theory

This task is simple, but is there a solution based on some theory? Not just going through all graphs on 5 vertices.

Comment: Does "$22, 13, 12$ cycles" mean something other than "$22$ cycles, $13$ cycles and $12$ cycles"?

Comment: @Arthur, of course not, It is three different graphs. I'm sorry, I thought that it was obvious.

Comment: It was almost obvious. But some times, a textbook author can invent some funky notation just for the context of a single problem, and the student solving it may think that it is conventional but somewhat niche notation, expecting that anyone who knows a bit of theory has heard of it. I just wanted to make sure that that wasn't the case.

Comment: Since the graphs are not required to be simple, you could just have as many self loops on the same vertex as  needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One hint: any graph $G$ has a [cycle space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_space). Every element of this is a subset $S$ of $G$'s edges where each node of $G$ meets an even number of edges in $S$. Thus every cycle in $G$ is a member of the cycle space. Where $G$ has $n$ nodes, $m$ edges and $c$ components, $G$'s cycle space has $2^{m-n+c}$ elements. So if $n=5$ and $G$ has 22 cycles, $G$'s cycle space needs at least $2^5$ elements...